# Comma issue in modal pop up

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

n the login section I have a username, password textbox, submit button and forgot password link button. All are encapsulated in an update panel. On entering invalid login username / password, a lable displays error message as 'Invalid username/password'. After that when I click on forgot password, a modal pop up opens which contains username/emailid text boxes. The problem is the text boxes displays comma(,) in the textbox automatically. I tried to clear the textbox value (comma) using javascript on forgot password link button click but i am not able to clear that textbox values.Hope u can better understand now!

Comment: I am not able to send the entire source code since it exceeds the minimum number of characters allowed for comment. I have an update panel inside which username,password textboxes are present, under that submit button and forgot password link button are present. On clicking forgot password link button, a modal popup containing username, password textboxes opens up. I have given post back trigger as forgot password link button for the update panel. When I enter invalid username/password and click on forgot password link button, the modal pop up opens up but the textboxes in it contain commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have placed the modal pop up panel outside the update panel and now the comma does not appear except that the flickering effect occurs due to reloading of controls present inside modal pop up.